# open omp slower than without it

Tags: performance, openmp

I'm new in "parallelization". I'm trying to parallelize an easy code to get a better performance, but I'm having very bad runtimes.
here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<omp.h>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;
double omp_get_wtime(void);

int main(){
const double starttime = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(10)
            {
            cout<<"sbam"<<endl;
            }
const double endtime = omp_get_wtime();
    cout << "work took time: " << endtime-starttime << " s"<<endl;
    cout << "work took time: " << (endtime-starttime)*1000000.00 << " mus"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

what am I doing wrong?? thank you!!

Comment: hey, you're writing to console...it's not an operation that will benefit of threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the console is an exclusive resource and when 10 threads want to use it at the 'same time' locking is needed!

that add. locking adds overhead and that explains the times you are seeing

---

btw the same goes for disk access or rather any exclusive / limited resource

Comment: can I actually fix this problem?? Thanks'

Comment: Use OpenMP on a real code, not a toy example that has no parallelism. When you do that you would also be wise *not* to force the number of threads, since that will very likely over-subscribe some machines and under-subscribe others, which is bad for performance either way!